# Bash function with weird AND and OR result

Tags: bash

Function:

```
function executeTcpConnetions() {
    host=$1
    port=$2
    max=$3

    trues=0
    falses=0
    count=0

    while [ $count -lt $max ]
    do
            timeout 2 bash -c "</dev/tcp/$host/$port" && ((trues++)) || ((falses++));
            ((count++))
    done

    echo $trues $falses }
```

I am seeing if you call that function with max=1,  echo will return 1 for trues and 1 for falses. But why in the first iteration both both bash aritimetic are being executed? If you provide 1000 or any value greater than 1, it will work as I thought.

The idea is test tcp connection if is able to connect... and if yes, add 1 in trues... if no, add 1 in falses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `(( expression ))`
>
> Returns 1 if `EXPRESSION` evaluates to 0; returns 0 otherwise.

If you use post-increment and the variable is equal to 0, the expression will evaluate to 0 and 1 will be returned:

```
$ var=0
$ ((var++)) || echo failed
failed
$ var=10
$ ((var-10)) || echo failed
failed
$ var=-1
$ ((++var)) || echo failed
failed
```

---

You can use pre-increment instead:

```
$ var=0
$ ((++var)) && echo ok
ok
```

Or you can use an `if` statement:

```
if timeout 2 bash -c "</dev/tcp/$host/$port"; then
    ((trues++))
else 
    ((falses++))
fi
```

I also recommend checking out [Bash Pitfall #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) explaining why `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` doesn't equal to `if ... then ... else ... fi`.

Comment: I'd definitely prefer the `if ... then ... else ... fi` option -- there're just fewer ways it can fail.